# Rcpp jupyter notebooks

Tags: r, linux, jupyter-notebook, rcpp

I have installed Rcpp in the R console with this command that until now ussually works for installing packages to run on jupyter notebooks:

```
install.packages('Rcpp', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/R/library/')
```

Then in the console I do:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("2+2")
```

and it works, but when I do the same on Jupyter notebooks it does not work, giving me this error message:

> /home/tyatabe/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ 
>   -I/home/tyatabe/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I'/home/tyatabe/anaconda3/lib/R/library/SimInf/include'  -I"/home/tyatabe/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/tmp/RtmpC4usUT/sourceCpp-x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-0.12.15" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/tyatabe/anaconda3/include   -fpic  -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -flto -ffat-lto-objects  -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -c file345f2e80a7c7.cpp -o file345f2e80a7c7.o
>   /home/tyatabe/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:167: recipe for target
>   'file345f2e80a7c7.o' failed Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env,
>   rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, : Error 1 occurred building
>   shared library. Traceback:
>
> 1. evalCpp("2+2")
> 2. cppFunction(code, depends = depends, plugins = plugins, includes = includes,   .     env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,
>      showOutput = showOutput,   .     verbose = verbose)
> 3. sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,   .     showOutput = showOutput, verbose = verbose)
> 4. stop("Error ", status, " occurred building shared library.")
>
> WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.
>
> Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.

I'm running on a 64 bit machine with Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas on how can I make Rcpp work on jupyter?

Thanks,

Tada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DirkEddelbuettel mentioned... Anaconda isn't ideal on Ubuntu...

If you *really* want to have this setup, there was a recent entry to the [Rcpp FAQ](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/commit/bc994733eaa3d63f7244e6ff707c157dae1b16ff#diff-ad47f9dc243ec46bfd31a3d10ecb8837) regarding compilers and Anaconda... In particular, we have:

> In a comment to [issue ticket#770](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/770#issuecomment-346716808)
>   it is stated that running
>
> ```
> sh conda install gxx_linux-64
> ```
>
> helps within this enivronment as it installs the corresponding
>   `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++` compiler.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @coatless ! I'll consider leaving anaconda, as it seems like is not the best option

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend not to mix Ubuntu (where everything works as is) and Anaconda (which sometimes gets in the way).

And I have use Jupyter notebooks just fine on my box too.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you're a big anaconda fan just install jupyter through pip.

Comment: Or `apt-get`.  Can't speak to 16.04 but on 17.10 it looks like fine and ready.  For both Python flavors.

Comment: Oh, right, on 16.04 it is still called `ipython-notebook`.  I used that in the past too.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I'll consider quiting anaconda for my future projects