# C++ Compiler Issues with Jupyter Notebook using Rcpp Package

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, rcpp

I am trying to run the following code:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("2+2", verbose=TRUE)
```

through a jupyter notebook using an anaconda environment.

The same code works fine through the terminal when I run using the same anaconda environment but does not work in Jupyter notebook and fails with the error:

```
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, : Error 1 occurred building shared library.
Traceback:

1. evalCpp("2+2", verbose = TRUE)
2. cppFunction(code, depends = depends, plugins = plugins, includes = includes, 
 .     env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, showOutput = showOutput, 
 .     verbose = verbose)
3. sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, 
 .     showOutput = showOutput, verbose = verbose)
4. stop("Error ", result, " occurred building shared library.")


WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.
```

I tired following another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649359/rcpp-jupyter-notebooks) and installed however that does help.

Comment: Your `$PATH` differs between the shell and your notebook, and the latter one sees no compiler.  You need to fix that.  That has nothing to with Rcpp -- it is "missing" as far as Jupyter is concerned.

Comment: Thank you! That answers the question. I changed the path and it works.